# MailChimp Auto Popup on exit

Tags: mailchimp

I have setup a mailchimp popup that offers a discount before a user can exit my website. Everything works fine except for when a user fills in the data and doesn't exit out of the response popup (it auto closes after 3 seconds). When it auto closes, the next time the users mouse goes outside of the screen (triggers another popup, which it shouldn't because it has already for this user), it shows only the bottom part of the modal. There are no Javascript crashes showing in the console.

Any ideas what is causing this?

[Here is the popup:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5g9ZW.png)

[Here is the popup that shouldnt be showing:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZqg7.png)

Here is the script that mailchimp provided to put into my website html:
window.dojoRequire(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us17.list-manage.com","uuid":"4f6184cb308c27717022f5cd5","lid":"6eab79ca61","uniqueMethods":true}) })

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's impossible to even guess what the problem might be. Side note: you're using JavaScript, not Java. They are completely different languages.

Comment: Updated description with the code. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I know its 10 months old question but I am having the exact issue, @ChaseHuff - did you manage to fix this?